# Copy a file from container to host during build process

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-build

How do I copy files from a docker container to the host machine during `docker build` command?

As a part of building my docker image for my app, I'm running some tests inside it, and I would like to copy the output of the test run into the host (which is a continuous integration server) to do some reporting.

Comment: Why not just run the tests after the build?

Comment: Why would I build it if the tests are not passing?

Comment: [How to copy files from dockerfile to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33377022/6521116)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't run the tests during build, this will only increase the size of your image. I would recommend you to build the image and then run it mounting a host volume into the container and changing the working directory to the mount point.

```
docker run -v `pwd`/results:/results -w /results -t IMAGE test_script
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this.  Volumes are only created at run time.  You can grab it out of the docker filesystem, (e.g. mine is /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/CONTAINER_ID/rootfs/PATH_TO_FILE) though there is no good way to figure out when your test process is complete.  You could create a file when it's finished and do an inotify, but this is ugly.