# How to copy files from dockerfile to host?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I want to get some files when dockerfile built successfully, but it doesn't copy files from container to host.

That means when I have built dockerfile, the files already be host.

Comment: [Docker - copy file from container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22049212/6521116)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copying files "from the Dockerfile" to the host is **not** supported. The Dockerfile is just a recipe specifying how to build an image.

When you build, you have the opportunity to copy files from host to the image you are building (with the [`COPY` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) or [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add))

You can also copy files from a *container* (an image that has been `docker run`'d) to the host with [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) (atually, the cp can copy from the host to the container as well)

If you want to get back to your host some files that might have been generated during the build (like for example [calling a script](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1a3a147bb59a209f1cedd0c37c4a2cddef3d6ea5/apache/Dockerfile#L48) that [generates ssl](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1a3a147bb59a209f1cedd0c37c4a2cddef3d6ea5/apache/gen_ssl_key_and_crt.sh#L30)), you can run a container, mounting a folder from your host and executing cp commands.

See for example this [getcrt script](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/apache/getcrt).

```
docker run -u root --entrypoint=/bin/sh --rm -i -v ${HOME}/b2d/apache:/apache apache << COMMANDS
pwd
cp crt /apache
cp key /apache
echo Changing owner from \$(id -u):\$(id -g) to $(id -u):$(id -u)
chown -R $(id -u):$(id -u) /apache/crt
chown -R $(id -u):$(id -u) /apache/key
COMMANDS
```

Everything between `COMMANDS` are commands executed on the container, including `cp` ones which are copying on the host `${HOME}/b2d/apache` folder, mounted within the container as `/apache` with `-v ${HOME}/b2d/apache:/apache`.

That means each time you copy anything on `/apache` in the container, you are actually copying in `${HOME}/b2d/apache` on the host!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   So particular, I will have a try.

Comment: How can we achieve this from dockerfile ??

Comment: @SudarP I thought this 2015 answer was to say it could not be done? What is your specific use case for this?

Comment: There could be use cases where you need to copy back to the host explicitly during build time, not during a later container run time. For example, suppose you have a multi-stage build where within one build stage you execute some unit tests and write a test coverage report. You need this to pass during specifically the build phase - failed tests should fail the build, and not occur in a later container run. But you might also need to retrain the code coverage report files for other uses outside of any image or container.

Comment: On top of this, the whole process could be running in a CI/CD system where it is expensive to pull the Docker container and run it in a whole new CI/CD step just for purposes of copying out a file - you truly need it to happen within the same CI/CD process where the build is happening, not any later container pull + run.

Comment: @ely Good points. Multi-stage builds did not exist when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 82):

This is now possible since Docker 19.03.0 in July 2019 introduced "custom build outputs". See the official docs about [custom build outputs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#output).

To enable custom build outputs from the build image into the host during the build process, you need to activate the **BuildKit** which is a newer recommended back-compatible way for the engine to do the build phase. See the official docs for [enabling BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds).

This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Set the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, or
2. Set it in the docker engine by default by adding `"features": { "buildkit": true }` to the root of the config json.

From the official docs about [custom build outputs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#output):

> custom exporters allow you to export the build artifacts as files on the local filesystem instead of a Docker image, which can be useful for generating local binaries, code generation etc.
>
> ...
>
> The local exporter writes the resulting build files to a directory on the client side. The tar exporter is similar but writes the files as a single tarball (.tar).
>
> If no type is specified, the value defaults to the output directory of the local exporter.
>
> ...
>
> The --output option exports all files from the target stage. A common pattern for exporting only specific files is to do multi-stage builds and to copy the desired files to a new scratch stage with COPY --from.

e.g. an example Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest AS stage1
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo "hello world" > output.txt

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=stage1 /app/output.txt .
```

Running

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --file Dockerfile --output out .
```

The tail of the output is:

```
 => [export-stage 1/1] COPY --from=stage1 /app/output.txt .
0.0s
 => exporting to client
0.1s
 => => copying files 45B
0.1s
```

This produces a local file `out/output.txt` that was created by the `RUN` command.

```
$ cat out/output.txt
hello world
```

#### All files are output from the target stage

The `--output` option will export **all** files from the target stage. So using a non-scratch stage with `COPY --from` will cause extraneous files to be copied to the output. The recommendation is to use a scratch stage with `COPY --from`.

---

Windows is not supported for now:

- https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/

Comment: this looked promising but for some reason I get files from different stages copied too. Is there any way to just get the output from this specific stage and not the others?

Comment: The `--from` flag is used to specify the stage to copy from.

Comment: In 2020 this should be the selected answer! This "IS" the way. Ben T => Thanks!

Comment: In 2021, it still works

Comment: its still working

Comment: NOTE: The `scratch` container is a "empty" container image built into Docker.  I am guessing that is why you don't get a bunch of operating system files.

Comment: How to only get the exact file, not all of the file in `/`? @Vaccano @Ben T

Comment: @gfan The example above already copies a single file. What are you seeing?

Comment: I tried to use different  images, like `FROM scratch ` or `FROM alpine`, If use alpine, it will copy all the file under `/`, but use scratch, it only copy the `output.txt`

Comment: @gfan This is the documented behavior. The docs state `The --output option exports **all** files from the target stage.`

Comment: Is there any way to specify "output" in a compose.yaml? So that a `docker compose build` will create my target file?

Answer (score 11):

Although it's not directly supported via the `Dockerfile` functionality, you can copy files from a built docker image.

```
containerId=$(docker create example:latest)
docker cp "$containerId":/source/path /destination/path
docker rm "$containerId"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now a much easier way of doing that using Docker's plugin **buildx**, with its [Local Exporter](https://docs.docker.com/build/exporters/local-tar/).

If you followed Docker's tutorial on installing Dokcer Engine or Desktop you should have buildx installed and activated as the default builder.

It exports everything from the root of the container to a local path on the host but you can use multi-stage build with the [scratch Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) to export only what you need:

```
#Stage 1: Build
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /build

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:doc

#Stage 2: Copy files to scratch image
FROM scratch AS export

COPY --from=builder /build/docs .
```

Then all you need to do is build with `--type=local, dest=<desired_path>`:

```bash
docker buildx build --output type=local,dest=. .
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could mount a folder from the host as a volume and put the files there? Usually mounted volumes could be written to from within the container, unless you specify read-only option while mounting.

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/<somewritablepath> -w <somewritablepath> <image> <action>
```

Answer (score 0):

On completion of **Docker Build** using **Dockerfile**, following worked for me :

where **/var/lib/docker/** is **Docker Root Dir:** at my setup.

```
sudo find /var/lib/docker/ -name DESIRED_FILE -type f | xargs sudo ls -hrt | tail -1 | grep tgz | xargs  -i  sudo cp -v  '{}' PATH_ON_HOST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the network.  Starting with the script from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58255859/836450

- I run this script on my host in the folder I want my output to go
- Inside my docker I have:

  RUN apt-get install -y curl
  RUN curl -F 'file=@/path/to/file' http://172.17.0.1:44444/

Note, for me at least, 172.17.0.1 is always the IP of the host while building the dockerfile