# dockerfile copying folder after a jest test completes

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile

Is there a way to copy test results directory from running container before it shuts down?

```
...
COPY tests tests
...
CMD ["yarn", "test"]
COPY /home/node/project/app/results results
```

I've tried `COPY` after or on same line (e.g, &&) as the `CMD` but that has not worked.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377022/how-to-copy-files-from-dockerfile-to-host) helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy files from dockerfile to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377022/how-to-copy-files-from-dockerfile-to-host)